# Simple wrapper around Java's File & FileInputStream

Tags: scala

In an attempt to begin learning Scala, I've taken a stab at creating a simple wrapper around Java's File & FileInputStream in order to read lines from a file. This functionality already exists in the Source class and is just a learning exercise.

If you were building this wrapper in Scala, is there anything you might change? Are there any best practices I'm overlooking?

```
////////// Driver.scala ////////////////

object Driver {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val uri = File.classpathResource("sample.txt")
    val fileReader = FileReader.open(uri)
    println("Reading File: " + fileReader.file.name() )
    for( val line <- fileReader.lines() ) {
      println(line)
    }
    fileReader.close()
  }

}

////////// File.scala ////////////////

import java.io.{File => JavaFile}
import java.net.URI

/** This object provides convenience methods for working with local file resources */
object File {

  /** Helper method to resolve a URI for a resource on the classpath
   *
   * @param the resource's path name
   * @return the resource's URI
   */
  def classpathResource(pathName: String): URI = {
    val url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(pathName)
    url.toURI()
  }

}

/** This class represents a file on the file system */
class File(val javaFile: JavaFile) {

  def this(pathName: String) = this(new JavaFile(pathName))
  def this(uri: URI) = this(new JavaFile(uri))  

  /** Get the file's file name */
  def name(): String = javaFile.getName()

  /** Get the file's absolute path */
  def path(): String = javaFile.getAbsolutePath()

  /** Open a new file reader. Call FileReader.close() once you have finished
   *  using the file reader.
   *  
   *  @return a new file reader instance
   *  @throws FileNotFoundException if the file cannot be opened for reading
   */
  def openReader(): FileReader = {
    new FileReader(this)
  }

}

////////// FileReader.scala ////////////////

import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.net.URI

/** This object provides convenience methods for reading files */
object FileReader {

  /** Creates and opens a FileReader class instance for a given file's path name
   * 
   * @param the file's path name
   * @return an instance of the File class
   * @throws FileNotFoundException if the file cannot be opened for reading
   */
  def open(pathName: String): FileReader = this open new File(pathName)

  /** Creates and opens a FileReader class instance for a given file's URI
   * 
   * @param the file's URI
   * @return an instance of the File class
   * @throws FileNotFoundException if the file cannot be opened for reading
   */
  def open(uri: URI): FileReader = this open new File(uri)

  /** Creates and opens a FileReader class instance for a given File instance
   * 
   * @param a File instance
   * @return an instance of the FileReader class
   * @throws FileNotFoundException if the file cannot be opened for reading
   */
  def open(file: File): FileReader = new FileReader(file)

}


class FileReader(val file: File) {

  private val inputStream = new FileInputStream(file.javaFile)

  private val lineIterator = new BufferedLineIterator(inputStream);

  /** Read the file's lines using a string iterator
   *  
   *  @return file's line iterator (Iterator[String])
   */
  def lines(): Iterator[String] = lineIterator

  /** Closes the file reader */
  def close(): Unit = inputStream.close()

}


////////// BufferedLineIterator.scala ////////////////

import scala.collection.Iterator
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.InputStream

class BufferedLineIterator(inputStream: InputStream) extends Iterator[String] {

  /** Buffered reader for reading lines from the file */
  private val bufferedReader: BufferedReader = {
    val inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream)
    new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
  }

  /** Stores the next line waiting to be returned from the next() method */
  private var nextLine: String = null

  /** Identifies if the file has another line to read
   * 
   * @return boolean identifying if the file has another line to read
   */
  override def hasNext(): Boolean = {
    if( nextLine == null ) {
      nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine
    }
    nextLine != null
  }

  /** Reads the next line from the file
   * 
   * @return the line
   */
  override def next(): String = {
    try {
      if(hasNext) {
        nextLine
      } else {
        Iterator.empty.next
      }
    } finally {
      nextLine = null
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Looks pretty good! The only big thing I found out is in the for-comprehension: don't use `val` there. In 2.10 it's use is forbidden. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Looks ok. A `Traversable` is a more interesting way to do this, since you can then auto-close the resource. There's one thing I took an issue to:

```
private val inputStream = new FileInputStream(file.javaFile)

private val lineIterator = new BufferedLineIterator(inputStream);

def lines(): Iterator[String] = lineIterator
```

The first two being `val` means this cannot be reused. However, if you turn them into `def`, then `lines` will already return a valid iterator.